# How do I get the seed from a Random with a bound in Java?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

```
int[] pos = (random.nextInt(16) - random.nextInt(16), random.nextInt(8) - random.nextInt(8), random.nextInt(16) - random.nextInt(16));
```

Hello,
Can I calculate the seed from the following code with the 3 numbers that come out of the calculation?

I can only find examples to find out the `java.until.random` seed without a bound in the numbers.

Comment: In your example code, Should the leftmost `(` be '{` and the rightmost `)` be `}` ?  Also, your example should show how `random` is declared and initialized. Is it `Random random = new Random ()`, or what?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not enough information to find the random seed.

The seed is a value with 48 bits: if a `Random` instance gives you a specific `int` value (with 32 bits) you can deduce that the seed currently has one of 65_536 possible values.

When you call `random.nextInt(16)` the result is one of 16 possible values - which means there are 17_592_186_044_416 possible seed values that can produce that specific result. By calling `random.nextInt(16)` several times and storing the returned values you could reduce that search space by at most 1/16th for every generated random number in the range 0-15.

But by calculating `random.nextInt(16) - random.nextInt(16)` you loose much of the information that could be gained - if the difference is 0 you don't know if both calls returned 0, both returned 1, both returned 2, ..., both returned 15. Likewise if the difference is 1 it could be that the first call returned 1 and the second call 0, the first call could have returned 2 and the second call 1, etc....

There are billions and billions possible seed values that can generate the same sequence of three values that you store in `int[] pos`.

Answer (score 0):

`"Can I calculate the seed from the following code with the 3 numbers that come out of the calculation?"`

No...I don't think you can, but you can keep track of them via the index number of the returned value in question from the `pos` array by placing the seeds in 2D int[][] array. For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[][] seeds = {{16, 16}, {8, 8}, {16, 16}};

int[] pos = new int[seeds.length];
for (int i = 0; i < seeds.length; i++) {
    pos[i] = random.nextInt(seeds[i][0]) - random.nextInt(seeds[i][1]);
}
    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
System.out.println("Random Values Generated:\n"
                 + "------------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
    sb.setLength(0);
    sb.append("Random `pos` value at Index #").append(i).append(" is ")
            .append(pos[i]).append(" from seed(s): ");
    for (int j = 0; j < seeds[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(seeds[i][j]);
        if (j < seeds[i].length - 1) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Output to Console window would look something like this:

```
Random Values Generated:
------------------------
Random `pos` value at Index #0 is 3 from seed(s): 16, 16
Random `pos` value at Index #1 is 1 from seed(s): 8, 8
Random `pos` value at Index #2 is 4 from seed(s): 16, 16
```

Answer (score -1):

You just get the seed. Period.

The bound is mostly irrelevant to the value of the seed.[1]

Here are some excerpts from the [source code for java.util.Random](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html):

```
protected synchronized int next(int bits)
{
   seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
   return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

And

```
public int nextInt(int n)
{
  if (n <= 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
  if ((n & -n) == n) // i.e., n is a power of 2
   return (int) ((n * (long) next(31)) >> 31);
  int bits, val;
  do
    {
     bits = next(31);
     val = bits % n;
    }
  while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);
  return val;
}
```

Note the value of `seed` is calculated in `next (int bits)`. It "knows" only the current value of `seed` and the number of desired bits.

Note within `nextInt (int n)`, where `n` is the bound, `next` is always called with a value of `31`. So, `next (int bits)` knows nothing about the bound.

[1] Note some values of the bound can result in `next()` being called more than once within `nextInt(int n)`. That seems to be the only way a bound can affect the value of `seed`.

[2] This answer does not explain why you cannot take the results of some calls to nextInt (int n) and calculate the seed from the results. An [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76689066/how-do-i-get-the-seed-from-a-random-with-a-bound-in-java/76689385#76689385) does a good with that that. This answer is supplementary, and is a response to the "I can only find examples to find out the java.until.random seed without a bound in the numbers" part of the question.